# python - bottle+gevent cannot serve static files

Tags: python, gevent, bottle

I'm using [bottle](http://bottlepy.org) with [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) for my python webdev experiments.
My problem is that I can't serve static files, e.g. use external css in my templates.
My folders structure is: **/static/css/style.css**

My code:

**index.py**

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all() #patching default Python threads
from bottle import mount, run, debug #initializing bottle
from routes import root #importing site routes
debug( True )
run( app = root , host = '0.0.0.0' , port = 80 , server = 'gevent' )
```

**routes.py**

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from bottle import *
root = Bottle()

@root.get('/static/<path:path>')
def serve_files( path ):
    return static_file( path , root = '/static/' )
```

**Here is my traceback from terminal:**

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [2011-12-22 09:36:44] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 500 161 0.002867
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent-0.13.6-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 438, in handle_one_response
    self.run_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent-0.13.6-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 424, in run_application
    self.result = self.application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle-0.10.4-py2.7.egg/bottle.py", line 849, in __call__
    return self.wsgi(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle-0.10.4-py2.7.egg/bottle.py", line 841, in wsgi
    % (html_escape(repr(_e())), html_escape(format_exc(10)))
NameError: global name '_e' is not defined
```

Please, help.

**UPDATE:**

I've downloaded unstable version of Bottle (version 0.11) and import it into my script. Now there is no 500 errors and tracebacks, but style.css gives me 404.

```
[2011-12-22 12:42:59] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 122 0.000591
```

Comment: [`_e()`](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L38)

Comment: I don't clearly understand you comment. Could you please repeat it for dummies? :)

Comment: It seems like a bug in `bottle.py`. Define `bottle._e = lambda: sys.exc_info()[1]` as a workaround.

Comment: please look at the update of question.

Comment: I too am getting 404 with version 0.11 unstable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 404 is because probably your root path to static files is wrong.

`root='/static/'` is ok only if you have a `static` folder in your root file system. Probably it is not what you really have. If you have a project folder and inside this folder you have a `static` folder, use `root='./static/'` and it will work fine.

Comment: @gabeDel I've completely forgot to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered, but if you want something more production oriented, whitenoise is awesome.

```
from app import appRoute
from client import clientRoute
from main import mainRoute
from api import apiRoute
from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware
from whitenoise import WhiteNoise
if whitecompress:
    static_compress(whitecompress) # auto mins and gzips all js and css files
botapp = bottle.app()
for nftyRoute in (mainRoute, appRoute, clientRoute, apiRoute):          
    botapp.merge(nftyRoute)
botapp = SessionMiddleware(botapp, beaker_opts)
botapp = WhiteNoise(botapp)
botapp.add_files(staticfolder, prefix='static/')
botapp.add_files('{}/common/img/favicon.ico'.format(staticfolder), prefix='favicon.ico')
print('WhiteNoise Enabled')
WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", int(port)), botapp, handler_class=WebSocketHandler).serve_forever()
```

This allows you to post your static files, and it will also handle delivering gzipped files for you automatically.  I find this solution a tad more robust than the option built into bottle.